# test a string if it contains the desired value put a tick in front of it

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have a table with 3 columns , I am getting the values in first column from the databse.

If the value of first column contains **IN** then I place a "X" in the corresponding second column in the same row else I ll put a cross in **OUT**.

My problem is for eg I have 4 IN and 4 OUT in the option name of the first column not in the same order , my check is failing, it just goes through the loop and place "X" in first 4 rows of IN and same applies to the "X" in first 4 rows of OUT. instead of leaving the row it doesnt contain **IN** or **OUT**

```
<table border="5" ><tr>
                <th>value</th>
                <th>IN</th>     
                <th>OUT</th>
          </tr>
          <tr><td> 
        <c:forEach items="${abc}" var="user"> 
                <option value="${user.name}">${user.name}</option><br>

         </c:forEach> 
       </td>
       <td>
            <c:forEach items="${abc}" var="user"> 

                     <c:if test="${not fn:containsIgnoreCase(user.name, 'IN')}">
                        <option>X</option><br>
                    </c:if>

         </c:forEach> 
       </td>
       <td>
            <c:forEach items="${abc}" var="user"> 

                     <c:if test="${not fn:containsIgnoreCase(user.name, 'OUT')}">
                        <option>X</option><br>
                    </c:if>

         </c:forEach> 
       </td>
       </tr>
       </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution of your problem is that:

```
    <c:forEach items="${abc}" var="user"> 
      <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(user.name, 'IN')}">
                <option>X</option><br>
            </c:when >
            <c:otherwise>
                <option>Y</option>
            </c:otherwise>
     </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, Will do 2 tests instead of one.

```
<c:if test="${ fn:containsIgnoreCase(user.name, 'IN')}">
                        <option>X</option><br>
                    </c:if>
<c:if test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(user.name, 'OUT')}">
                        <option></option><br>
                    </c:if>
```